# onMouseEnter on a cell of antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have created a table using the antd table component.

```
   const dataSource = [{
        key: '1',
        value1: 4,
        value2: 19,
        value3: 12
    },{
        key: '2',
        value1: 5,
        value2: 9,
        value3: 2
    },{
        key: '3',
        value1: 14,
        value2: 39,
        value3: 24
    }];

    const columns = [{
        title: 'Title One',
        dataIndex: 'value1',
        key: 'value1'
    },{
        title: 'Title Two',
        dataIndex: 'value2',
        key: 'value2'
    },{
        title: 'Title Three',
        dataIndex: 'value3',
        key: 'value3'
    }];

   <Table
       dataSource={dataSource}
       columns={columns}
   />
```

[image]

And now I need to change the value of a specific cell for a specific text when the cursor passes over it.

For example, the value 4 of the first cell by the text 'Example text'.

And when you remove the course, return to the previous value.

Would it be something similar to this?

```
   <Table
       onRow={(e) => {
         return {onMouseEnter: () => {.....}};}}
       dataSource={dataSource}
       columns={columns}
   />
```

Comment: You need to replace the value 4 or show tooltip like 'Example Text' when the mouse passes over ?

Comment: I need show tooltip like 'Example Text' when the mouse passes over

Comment: check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypejma , is this you need ?

Comment: Yes, I think this can help me. Although I think it would be better to change the text for another when the mouse passes over. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: instead tooltip you need to replace value '4' ?

Comment: I need that when I pass the mouse over a cell, I change the value '4' to 'Example text' and when the cursor is not over, the value '4' will return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a another component and add onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events to it, for example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Cell extends Component {
  state = {
    hover: false
  };
  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: !this.state.hover });
  };
  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: !this.state.hover });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      >
        {this.state.hover ? this.props.hoverText : this.props.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then use this component in a Row inside:

```
const dataSource = [{
  key: '1',
  value1: <Cell text="4" hoverText="Example Text" />,
  value2: <Cell text="19" hoverText="Example Text" />,
  value3: <Cell text="12" hoverText="Example Text" />
},
...
];

const columns = [{
  title: 'Title One',
  dataIndex: 'value1',
  key: 'value1'
},
...
];

<Table
 dataSource={dataSource}
 columns={columns}
/>
```

Comment: This is just what I needed and it works perfectly. You made my day. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad to help!

Comment: Hi @MohsinAli where did you find you can pass a component to the data source value, in the document there is no clue on that? can you give me some links to learn more about Antd table and how to customize it thanks.

Comment: Hey @MuneebEjaz I just used basic concept that a variable or object key can store a component and react can render it. So this table also renders it the same way.